# Find the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2 + (-1)^n}{2^{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit of a) $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2 + (-1)^n}{2^{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}} $ and b) $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a^n - b^n}{a^{n} + b^{n}} $

So im kinda confused on both of them. For I was thinking of just taking out both $(-1)$ s and just taking the limit of $2/2^{n+1}$. And for b) im thinking that it converges to 1 if a > b and if a < b then it convereges to -1.... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You must *know* what happens to the first one as $n$ gets big.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes is know that it does end up converging to 0 but how do i show it?

Comment: Show that the top is always $\le 3$ (easy) and that the bottom is $\ge 2^n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you. Do u have any suggetions for b) ?

Comment: For part b), it depends whether $a > b$ or $a < b$ ($a = b$ is easy).  You should break it into cases and divide the numerator and denominator by whichever is larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do the second. There are several cases.

If $b=-a$, then the expression is not even defined for odd $n$, so certainly the limit does not exist.

If $a=b\ne 0$, then our expression is always $0$, so the limit is $0$.

It remains to deal with the cases where $|a|\ne |b|$. There are two possibilities, $|a|\gt |b|$ and $|b|\gt |a|$. We deal with the first possibility, and let you deal with the second.

If $|a|\gt |b|$, divide top and bottom by $a^n$. We get
$$\frac{  1-\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n }{1+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n}.$$

Since $|a|\gt |b|$, the limit as $n\to\infty$ of $\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n$ is $0$, and therefore our limit is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the second has an answer then let's do the first one.

We have:

$$\require{mathtools}0\le \left|\frac{2 + (-1)^n}{2^{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}}\right| \le\frac{3}{2^{n+1}-1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
so the desired limit is $0$ using the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Nice work, Sami!